# ListView using parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Hey i am trying to fetch all the data from parse.com table.
My Table called "Code_Description" and i have two column that i have made into my table data they called "surveyCode" , "Description".
and i want to fetch them into listView the surveyCode and the Description .
please help.

i have this code but doesn't working .

```
public class editSurveyManager extends ActionBarActivity {

//List<ParseObject> ob;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_survey_manager);

    //Setting Data
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(editSurveyManager.this,R.layout.activity_edit_survey_manager);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Code_Description");
    query.setLimit(1000);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> markers, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // update your list here somehow
                // listAdapter.clear();
                // listAdapter.addAll(markers);
                for (ParseObject list : markers){
                    adapter.add((String)list.get("surveyCodes"));
                }
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else {
                Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: where is your listview in code?

Comment: //Setting Data
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(editSurveyManager.this,R.layout.activity_edit_survey_manager);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        
for (ParseObject list : markers){
                        adapter.add((String)list.get("surveyCodes"));
                    }
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: im trying to get the 2 column data to display them into list view

Comment: You have to write a custom adapter to do this, please see here: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: okay man this is about the adapter and the list view but how i could get the data from the two column using one query.?!
to fetch all the data from the two column and then i will put them into list view using a custom adapter

Comment: It is written in [Parse Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide) clearly. You have to call:

parseObject.getString("surveyCodes");
parseObject.getString("Description");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line is wrong. You should do something like that:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Code_Description");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> markers, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // update your list here somehow
            // listAdapter.clear();
            // listAdapter.addAll(markers);

        } else {
            Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Parse will give you top 100 rows of your table. But you can change it with that method below:

```
query.setLimit(1000); // max number you can set is 1000
```

Comment: Im trying to use this code

public void done(List<ParseObject> markers, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // update your list here somehow
                    // listAdapter.clear();
                    // listAdapter.addAll(markers);
                    for (ParseObject list : markers){
                        adapter.add((String)list.get("surveyCodes"));
                    }
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
                }

Comment: could you please edit your first post with your listview code?